# How to fix endless "checking whether stripping libraries is possible" when installing gmp with Mingw32

Tags: codeblocks, gmp, mingw32, msys

I'm trying to install GMP on my CodeBlocks application using MINGW32.

For this i use the command : ./configure *--prefix=/c/"Program Files (x86)"/CodeBlocks

The configuration advance until the step "checking whether stripping libraries is possible..." and then it seems an endless loop is started...

Therefor the configuration is not working and i cannot continue the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Check `config.log` to see if you can determine where it is stuck. You should be able to find the line numbers of the `configure` script where it's in a loop.

Try to run `which strip` and `strip --version` to check which `strip`is found in your `PATH` and if it's really GNU strip from Binutils.

Also, avoid paths with spaces in them when using `./configure`, so maybe try with a different `--prefix` path.